# TabStrip kendo UI is not working

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Im trying to set up a kendo tabstrip with some nested grids. The first tab loads fine with the nested grid, however, the when I click on the second tab, the tabStrip is not toggling to the second one. I even downloaded the example from kendo and it does not work either! I have imported all the kendo js files (including .all and .tabstrip files). But it does not work. Im using jquery 1.7 and MVC 4. This is the example I have from kendo site. Besides that O have the css they provide. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
<div id="forecast">
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
      .Name("Menu")
      .Items(tabstrip =>
      {
          tabstrip.Add().Text("Paris")
              .Selected(true)
              .Content(@<text>
                <div class="weather">
                    <h2>17<span>&ordm;C</span></h2>
                    <p>Rainy weather in Paris.</p>
                </div>
                <span class="rainy">&nbsp;</span>
              </text>);

          tabstrip.Add().Text("New York")
              .Content(@<text>
                <div class="weather">
                    <h2>29<span>&ordm;C</span></h2>
                    <p>Sunny weather in New York.</p>
                </div>
                <span class="sunny">&nbsp;</span>
              </text>);

          tabstrip.Add().Text("Moscow")
              .Content(@<text>
                <div class="weather">
                    <h2>16<span>&ordm;C</span></h2>
                    <p>Cloudy weather in Moscow.</p>
                </div>
                <span class="cloudy">&nbsp;</span>
              </text>);

          tabstrip.Add().Text("Sydney")
              .Content(@<text>
                <div class="weather">
                    <h2>17<span>&ordm;C</span></h2>
                    <p>Rainy weather in Sidney.</p>
                </div>
                <span class="rainy">&nbsp;</span>
              </text>);
      })
)
```

Comment: what version of KendoUI are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My mistake was related to jquery version, to use tabStrip component jquery 1.9.1 is required.

Thanks!
http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/javascript-dependencies

Comment: I also had this problem only I had to use the migrate js file right after the jquery.js file to correct errors in changes of version of jquery. http://jquery.com/download/